# here string in nested loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I got such a piece of bash code:

```
var="empty"

find $path1 -maxdepth 3  | while read line; do
find $path2 -maxdepth 1  | while read line2; do        
    if [[ $line2 != $var ]]; then
      echo "new value"
    fi
    var=$line2
 done <<< "$line2"
done
```

The question is... how to make `var` stay changed? Because I would like to echo on every new value found by loops but it doesn't work ;( `var="empty"` every time that the second loop starts iteration.

How to make `var=$line2` for every iteration?

Comment: Am I reading that wrong, or are you reading the value into line2 with a read from stdin, and feeding the value of line2 into the loop at the done with a here-string on stdin? I know there's a find pipe, but my bash gives the here-string precedence.

`echo -e "one\nthree\nfive" | while read num;
do echo $num;
done <<< "two";`  
Output is two. The input stream is totally ignored.

Comment: I know It is wrong. I just want to know how to make var stay as it was changed in loop. I made this topic becasue in similar someone signed as duplicate for here string.

Answer (score -1):

You are reading the value into line2 with a read from stdin, and feeding the value of line2 into the loop at the `done` with a here-string on stdin. bash gives the here-string precedence, so line2 is only ever being assigned from line2, which means it's never set.

```
echo -e "one\nthree\nfive" | while read num
do echo $num
done <<< "two"
```

Output is `two`. The input stream is totally ignored.

You are also defining a nested loop for no reason, since you are never using the outer loop. Clean your code before posting please.

```
find ~ | while read f; do var=$f; echo $f; done
```

This works fine.

Comment: I too am having a hard time understanding the question and his intent, however this should definitely be a comment and not an answer.